# Передача данных из RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent

хочу в этом куске кода

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    DialogFragment dlg;
    dlg = new barcodeView();
    Coupons coupons = coupons2.get(position);
    int i = coupons.getLogo();
    if (i == 2131165349){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,barcodeView.class);

        dlg.show(fragmentManager,"barcodeview");
    }
```

Из RecyclerAdapter где этот код находится передавать данные в DialogFragment но когда создаю intent как показано в моем отрывке кода получаю такой exception `Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.Activities.RecyclerAdapter, java.lang.Class<com.example.Classes.barcodeView>)'`

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: this в качестве контекста (первый аргумент в конструкторе интента) можно передавать только в классах Context и его наследниках (как классы активити). Класс адаптера к таким не относится и контекст в таких классах должен быть получен и указан явно, например передачей его из активити конструктором адаптера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для передачи данных между фрагментами можно использовать `Bundle`

```
DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("someValue", 5); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

А во втором фрагменте извлекаете данные

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt("someValue", 0); // 5
```

Ошибка возникала из-за того, что вы пытались создать `Intent` с аргументами, для которых не существует конструктора.

Comment: не можно, а нужно. к фрагменту интент не "прикрепляется", только к активити