# Как запустить фрагмент из адаптера RecyclerView, если RecyclerView запускается в другом фрагменте?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Когда я искал ответ на этот вопрос в интернете, то все примеры, которые мне встречались, создавались из расчёта на то, что `RecyclerView` создаётся в `Activity` и выглядели примерно так:

```
holder.send.setOnClickListener {
                val activity=it.context as AppCompatActivity
                activity.supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container,MessegeFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow()
        }
```

мне же нужно что-то подобное для тех случаев, когда `RecyclerView` создаётся внутри `Fragment`. Я реализовал обработчик нажатий внутри метода `bind` класса `MyViewHolder`:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener{
    Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
}
```

Теперь мне нужно реализовать запуск фрагмента с отправкой в него переменной `position` хранящей в себе информацию о позиции нажатого элемента, а затем получить эту переменную внутри запущенного фрагмента (как при использовании `Intent` в `Activity`)

...

```
class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){

        binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
        itemView.setOnClickListener{

          //  listener.itemClick(position, fragment)

            val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("someValue", 5)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle)

            val activity=it.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rd_fragment, fragment)
                .commitNow()

            Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Что именно у вас вызывает затруднение? Передать число? - через аргументы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987152/11515

Comment: @woesss, не только. Также не получается выполнить процесс запуска фрагмента в адаптере. Примеры, которые я нахожу, относятся либо к запуску из адаптера, работающего поверх `Activity`, либо к запуску фрагмента из фрагмента (без адаптера `recyclerview`)

Comment: @woesss, я использовал, приведённый по ссылке, кусок кода, для передачи переменной `position`, но переменную `fragment`, получается, в свою очередь, нужно тоже куда-то добавить, чтобы произошел запуск фрагмента, а вот куда, я пока что найти не могу

Comment: У вас сверху готовый пример запуска фрагмента, в него только нужно добавить передачу позиции. Код передачи лучше добавить в сам фрагмент в метод `newInstance(int position)`, добавив ему нужный параметр.

Comment: @woesss, пробовал (добавил, то, что получилось в текст вопроса), но у меня Intent, почему-то красным подчёркивается

Comment: А зачем вам Intent, где вы его увидели в обоих примерах кода? Вам фрагмент нужно запустить или активити?

Comment: сверху есть строка `Intent intent = new Intent(this,barcodeView.class);`

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на ответ, а вы взяли неправильный код из вопроса. Оттуда нужно взять передачу значения и поправить под свои нужды. А пример запуска фрагмента из обработчика клика у вас в вопросе - вы сами его опубликовали.

Comment: @woesss, фрагмент, почему-то не запускается (весь код `NameListHolder` я добавил в текст вопроса)